# Is there any guidelines regarding forms cancelling on iOS 13?

Tags: usability, gui-design, ios

iOS 13 added the “swipe to dismiss” feature to form sheets. I’m trying to find how to manage saving and cancelling on my forms to be as practical as possible.

[image: Agenda app form screenshot]

### On native apps

I took a look at iOS native apps, but they are not consistent:

- in Contacts, the form opens in full screen, and has a “Cancel” button that ask the user if he really wants to cancel his changes;
- in Reminders, the form opens in a form sheet, does not have any Cancel button, but will display a question if you swipe down.
- in Agenda, the form opens in a form sheet, but has a “Cancel” button, and will display a confirmation action sheet for both the swipe and the button…

[image: Agenda action sheet when dismissing or tapping the cancel button]

### What I want to do

I think that both the swipe down gesture and the cancel button may live together (like in Agenda app).

If there is no change, then I dont think I have to ask anything to the user (only dismiss the form). This is common on native iOS apps.

If there are any change, I was thinking about displaying different questions:

- if the user tapped on the Cancel button, only ask for a confirmation (the button is quite hard to reach);
- if the user swiped down, ask him what he prefers to do: saving his changes or dismissing them.

The swipe action is new, and quite easy to trigger when trying to scroll the form; it also may be a way for the user to cancel or save the form without having to reach the buttons at the top of the screen (which annoys me a lot).

Do you have any ideas or informations to improve this solution?